# SQOOP is not running on DSE

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, sqoop

I am compelety new on Cassandra, while i am importing from 
Mysql to Cassandra with Sqoop. This Error is there,

Hadoop functionality is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class job-tracker-address
Unable to start sqoop: jobtracker not found
```

How to solve it ,Please help..!!

Comment: Are you running an analytics cluster? What version are you on? Can you return the output of dsetool ring.

Comment: Whats the command you used? which cluster?

Comment: i am  using dse-5.0.3.

Comment: @NehaPal, Have you got solution? I have faced same issue.